# The inverse of matrix $A^TBA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Given tall matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ (where $m > n$) of full column-rank and non-singular matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, how to compute the following matrix inverse?

$$ \left( A^T B A \right)^{-1} $$

Comment: Did you want some mechanical guidance?  You could use Gauss-Jordan elimination.  Do you know $A$ and $B$?

Comment: You can take the [pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse): $(A^TBA)^{-1}=(A^TBA)^+=A^+B^+(A^+)^T$. One computes the pseudoinverses of $A$ and $B$ using SVD or Gauss-Jordan just as one does for the usual inverse, only with padded zero columns and a truncated identity matrix. Of course, it'd be easier to just compute the inverse of $A^TBA$ directly (if it exists), but I assume you wanted something symbolic, like in terms of inverses of $A$ and $B$ (they only have pseudoinverses when rectangular).